# ST_Area on a PolygonZ

Tags: postgis

The following code runs without error, even though my convex_hull column consists of PolygonZ (where the third dimension is always 0).

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   clusterss 
WHERE  st_area(convex_hull::geography) > 15
```

Can this be trusted to provide an accurate area of the 2D Polygon? (the third dimension is zero, I don't really need it). Please note my EPSG is 4326, so casting to geography works.

Comment: What makes you think it might not work?

Comment: By the documentation https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Area.html "a 2D Cartesian (planar) area is computed".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  As @user30184 pointed out, it's in the documentation that the 2D area is computed.  There is a different subset of functions for working with 3D geometry.  For example, st_3dArea: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_3DArea.html

When computing 2D area all coordinates except X and Y are ignored.

Comment: So in my case, where the third dimension coordinate is always zero, can I use st_area as I have mentioned in the question?

Comment: It makes no difference what the z coordinate is.  The function doesn't look at it at all.  Only X and Y.  That's what 2D means.